# PHPUnit 8 exit code 0 on database connection faluire

Tags: php, symfony, testing, automated-tests, phpunit

I'm running into what I think it's a strange behavior for PHPUnit (8.5.26 on PHP 7.4): if the database connection fails, the app throws an exception but the exit code is still 0.

Is this an expected behavior? Is there any parameter I can tweak to have it return non-zero? Thanks.

This is the output:

```
[08:22 AM]-[vagrant@web]-[/var/www/myapp]-[git github-action-run-test-fix-condition]
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit   --configuration=tests/phpunit.xml    --fail-on-warning  --stop-on-error --stop-on-failure  --testsuite Full --filter StringUtilTest -vv
Could not connect to database (myapp_testing).<pre>
PDOException: Could not connect to database (myapp_testing).

/var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php:473
#0 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php(166): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->connect()
#1 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php(543): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery()
#2 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Adapter/DBAdapter.php(118): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll()
#3 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/QueryWriter/AQueryWriter.php(1238): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->get()
#4 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Repository.php(453): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->queryRecord()
#5 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/OODB.php(333): RedBeanPHP\Repository->find()
#6 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Finder.php(199): RedBeanPHP\OODB->find()
#7 /var/www/myapp/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Facade.php(1012): RedBeanPHP\Finder->find()
#8 /var/www/myapp/library/App/Model/Repository/AbstractRepository.php(555): RedBeanPHP\Facade::find()
#9 /var/www/myapp/library/Myns/Auth/Acl.php(50): App\Model\Repository\AbstractRepository->all()
#10 /var/www/myapp/library/Myns/Auth/Acl.php(37): Myns\Auth\Acl->newSetupRoles()
#11 /var/www/myapp/library/App/Auth/Acl.php(13): Myns\Auth\Acl->setupRoles()
#12 [internal function]: App\Auth\Acl->__construct()
#13 /var/www/myapp/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(1142): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
#14 /var/www/myapp/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(618): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService()
#15 /var/www/myapp/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(558): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet()
#16 /var/www/myapp/library/App/DI/Definition/Authorization.php(42): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get()
#17 /var/www/myapp/library/App/DI/Definition/Authorization.php(26): App\DI\Definition\Authorization->load()
#18 /var/www/myapp/library/App/DI/Container.php(39): App\DI\Definition\Authorization::getInstance()
#19 /var/www/myapp/library/App/Bootstrap.php(281): App\DI\Container::get()
#20 /var/www/myapp/vendor/shardj/zf1-future/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(673): App\Bootstrap->_initAcl()
#21 /var/www/myapp/vendor/shardj/zf1-future/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(626): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
#22 /var/www/myapp/vendor/shardj/zf1-future/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(590): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
#23 /var/www/myapp/vendor/shardj/zf1-future/library/Zend/Application.php(389): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap()
#24 /var/www/myapp/tests/_bootstrap.php(22): Zend_Application->bootstrap()
#25 /var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(66): include_once('/var/www/Mynsc...')
#26 /var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/FileLoader.php(54): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load()
#27 /var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(1126): PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad()
#28 /var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(922): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleBootstrap()
#29 /var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(202): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments()
#30 /var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(194): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
#31 phpvfscomposer:///var/www/myapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(97): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#32 /var/www/myapp/vendor/bin/phpunit(118): include('phpvfscomposer:...')
#33 {main}

[08:23 AM]-[vagrant@web]-[/var/www/myapp]-[git github-action-run-test-fix-condition]
$ echo $?
0
```

This is `tests/phpunit.xml`:

```xml
<phpunit bootstrap="./_bootstrap.php"
         processIsolation="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         backupGlobals="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         stopOnRisky="false"
         cacheResult="true"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         failOnWarning="true"
         failOnRisky="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         cacheResultFile="./.phpunit.result.cache"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         colors="true">

    <testsuites>
[...]
        <testsuite name="Full">
            <directory>./Unit/App</directory>
            <directory>./App</directory>
            <directory>./Cron</directory>
            <directory>./Application/Extranet</directory>
            <directory>./Application/Api</directory>
        </testsuite>

    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
            <directory suffix=".php">../library</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APPLICATION_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```